# Default value Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I'm trying to set the default option of a Select List in MVC

I'm doing the following but it is not working

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CandidateOrderLine.SiteId, new SelectList(Model.Customer.Sites, "SiteId", "SiteName", Model.Customer.Sites.Where(x => x.IsPrimarySite == true).ToString()), "Select Site", new { @class = "form-control", @data_val_required = "Please select a site" })
```

Any help with this would be appreciated,

thanks

Chris

Comment: Delete your `Model.Customer.Sites.Where(x => x.IsPrimarySite == true` in the `SelectList` constructor (that is ignored when binding to a model property - its the value of `SiteId` that determines what is selected). If its value matches the value of one of the options, then that option will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your GET action is setting a valid SiteId value to the `Model.CandidateOrderLine.SiteId` property

*Just assuming your class names looks like these*

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm=new YourVideModelClass();
   vm.CandidateOrderLine= new CandidateOrderLine();
   vm.SiteId = 3; // Hard coded for demo. Replace with valid SiteId
   return View(vm);
}
```

This should work.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CandidateOrderLine.SiteId, 
         new SelectList(Model.Customer.Sites, "SiteId", "SiteName")), 
         "Select Site",
          new { @class = "form-control", @data_val_required = "Please select a site" })
```

This will select the option with the value which is matching to what we set in our GET action.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it ?
...Model.Customer.Sites.Where(x => x.IsPrimarySite == true).FirstOrDefault().ToString())...